# How can i scrape data from a HTML table which does not have URL? href contains 'on-click' link

Tags: python, web-scraping

With pythons beautiful soup, I am trying to scrape data from the 2nd table in the following url: https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/india/bangalore/historic?month=1&year=2018

Here I want to scrape the data for the complete Jan month of 2018, The URL for the page does not change for each date. Is there a way to scrape this kind.

How do I access each table, when the 'href' does not contain the whole data even if I edit the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think this site uses javascript to change this table. Take a look at `selenium` library ([useful link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)). It must help you with this kind of sites. You should just iterate over all the dates in the month, load a table and then **scrape** the data.

There are a lot of tutorials on how to use selenium so you shouldn't have much trouble with it

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code in you script..

```
params = {
        'n': 'india/bangalore',
        'mode': 'historic',
        'hd': '20180101',
        'month': '1',
        'year': '2018',
     }
   response = requests.get('https://www.timeanddate.com/scripts/cityajax.php', 
   params=params)
```

It returns a html table..
Now try changing the parameters to get desired output.

For example - 1st January 2018 >> 'hd': '20180101',
              2nd January 2018 >> 'hd': '20180102' and so on..
Hope its helpfull for you!!